# How to run Package Manager

Tags: package-management

I got an error message that said please run Package Manager from right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.

I don't know what right-click menu this refers to.

When I run apt-get update it says could not open lock file (permission denied)

Answer (score 3):

When you get permission denied try adding `sudo` before the command. Your commmand should be `sudo apt-get update`.